# Saving incomplete text in mysql database after & character

Tags: php, mysql

I have an input that accept text and extract links from it and when retrieving, it display a click able link, everything work fine until when a link with more than one variable is inserted, eg www.mysite,com/page.php?id=20&desc=How-to-by-this it drop anything after & character. When insertion, i used mysqli_real_escape_string and htmlentities yet its not accepting this (&) character. Please how should i escape it to be save in the database?
Below is my code sample
Thanks.

```
// Clean the posted variables
$osid = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['sid']);
$account_name = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['user']);
$data = $_POST['data'];
$data = urldecode($data); 
// I ALSO TRIED THIS BUT NOT SAVING & character
//$data = str_replace("&","&amp;",$data);
//$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $data);

// Insert the status reply post into the database now
$sql = "INSERT INTO status(osid, account_name, author, type, data, postdate)
       VALUES('$osid','$account_name','$log_username','b','$data',now())";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
```

Comment: have you checked your links before you try to insert them in database? do they have all the parameters? have you tried `urlencode( $url )`

Comment: I have done that, above is the code i used

Comment: ok tell me what is type of data's field in mysql? is it varchar? if yes change it to tinytext and try to code again

Comment: It was initially TEXT but changed to varcha and then to tinytext but not working

Comment: ok check my updated answer this is how i do it.... `base64`

Comment: base64? the data is not only a link, it can be description and a link added to it. All i want is to be able to save **&** character that is all.

Comment: ok mate but this is a way which is not the best but it can do it for you. if you have any problems using base64 let me know but i can't help you more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$e_url=urlencode($url);
```

to encode urls so you can save them. and use

```
$url=urldecode($e_url);
```

to decode encoded urls.

useful links:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php